# Sequelize not updating Meta table after applying migration

Tags: sequelize.js, database-migration, sequelize-cli

I don't know if I'm missing a step here or something, but `sequelize` is not updating the `SequelizeMeta` table after I run a migration.

If I run `db:migrate:status` I get that all my migrations are "up" but the last one, which doesn't even appears in the output.

Do I have to update this table manually?

[**EDIT**]

I've been looking more closely at the `sequelize db:migrate` command's output:

```
Executing (default): INSERT INTO "SequelizeMeta" ("name") VALUES ('20180827001615-updatePersonIdColumn.js') RETURNING *;

ERROR: null value in column "createdAt" violates not-null constraint
```

Looks like there is no default for the "createAt" column. Is this normal?

Answer (score 1):

From your error, it seems that SequelizeMeta has a wrong scheme (with a column named "createdAt").

Your "SequelizeMeta" table should have one and only one column named "name". If you created the scheme by hand and added a createdAt column, you could eventually change your table to make the createdAt column defaults to "now()", so you can keep track of when the migration was made.